# What is the Linear Transformation $[T]_\alpha^\beta $s.t $T(A) = Tr(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, trace

Define:
$T: P_2(R) \rightarrow F $ by $T(A) = Tr(A)$

Compute $T(A)_\alpha^\beta$

Where $\alpha = \left \{\begin{bmatrix}
 1&0 \\ 
 0&0 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
 0&1 \\ 
 0&0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 0&0 \\ 
 1&0 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
 0&0 \\ 
 0&1 
\end{bmatrix}   \right \}$ and $\beta = \left \{ 1 \right \}$

I have no idea where to begin: $T(A) = T(\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11} &a_{12}\\ 
a_{21} &a_{22}\end{bmatrix} \right ) = a_{11}a_{22} $
$$T(\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
1 &0\\ 
0 &0\end{bmatrix} \right )=1(0),$$
$$T(\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
0 &1\\ 
0 &0\end{bmatrix} \right )=(0)(0)$$
$$T(\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
0 &0\\ 
1 &0\end{bmatrix} \right )=(0)(0)$$
$$T(\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
0 &0\\ 
0 &1\end{bmatrix} \right )=1(0)$$

But then I just get a column of zeros... Can someone help!

Comment: The trace is the *sum* of the diagonal entries, not their product. Otherwise, everything looks okay (except that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ represent arbitrary elements of the bases, no the bases themselves, and there are a few misplaced left parentheses).

Comment: Trace was the sum thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. NB that the product of the diagonal entries does *not* define a linear map: Its value is zero for every element of some basis, but it is not the zero map.